# Error : Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment in Google Map V2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I could not find any answer for me. still this error is appearing...

AndroidManifest:

```
<permission android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="my_key" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and here is my activity:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and `map.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="mypackage.MapActivity"/>
```

So I can not find what is the problem...
this activity is called from another maybe it is the cause...
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? If so, could you post them?

Comment: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your xml like this

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

since fragment in xml expects a fragment class.

Also make sure your activity extends ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity since your using SupportMapFragment which extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Other problem is you need to set the content view only after super.onCreate called

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
}
```

Comment: does your activity extends ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity?

Comment: what was the error? Are you able to launch your app

Comment: the same situation as I mentioned in question. When my app is running and I am going to my map page (by clicking button) this error appears and app crashes

Comment: No. I bet this should work if your have changed the layout and if activity extends ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity.

Comment: post the complete stack trace log

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mapfriends.main/com.mapfriends.main.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: see my answer. move the setContentView below super.onCreate